# Catch a SOAP message send by SAP in a Apex Class

Tags: soap, salesforce, wsdl, apex, sap-erp

I need guidance with our current SAP - Salesforce situation.
We already have implemented a few outbound HTTP request classes.
However, in those classes, it was Salesforce which determined when to run the class and so, when to do the callout.

Our current SAP - Salesforce situation is a bit different. Every change in SAP sends a SOAP message from SAP. This has to be caught in an Apex Class.
So, I need some kind of listener that can catch the SOAP messages.

Do you have ay information to point me in the correct direction? Or even an example I can use to understand the best solution?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

I don't use SAP but I have the same setup with my ERP system.  I created a soap listener which i host locally to my ERP system which catches the messages.  The task here was simply take the message and then post it to a [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) message queue (this is so the callout from the ERP system is completed as quickly as possible).  Then I have a RabbitMQ consumer which uses the [SalesforceSharp](https://github.com/giacomelli/SalesforceSharp) library to process each message in turn.

The solution would work directly in the Soap project without RabbitMQ - certainly as a POC.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce has a SOAP API, you can generate a WSDL in Setup by navigating to the *API* page. See details here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_steps_generate_wsdl.htm

For more details wrt the SOAP API see the documentation here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm

If the SOAP API is not what you're looking for you could create a public REST API and consume messages that way. I would recommend securing such a REST endpoint with a Connected App Token and enforcing restricted domain access for the Connected App. See more details here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/REST_API
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=connected_app_overview.htm&type=5